# How to best integrate existing database data in a content type

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have an existing database (SQL) with relational data (for example with various 1-n and m-n relationships) that I would like to integrate into a Orchard CMS based website.  That database has a ASP.NET Dynamic Data as the backend data maintenance application.

What I would like to do is integrate this information into Orchard, i.e. use Orchard CMS to surface the information to the users. Furthermore, I would like to take advantage of Orchard's concept to extend a content type with further functionality (example tagging, comments).

But: I struggle with finding the best way to integrate that data without creating a complicated maintenance process (creating a content part where one would have to specify the Id of the item in my existing database).

Unfortunately, I did not find any sample for what I would like to achieve... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If you have an existing, complex database, moving it to Orchard storage system completely would be a **very** painful process...

The best option would be to keep the existing data in the current database, the Orchard content in second one and wire them together (feed the content part with appropriate data from your primary db) on a **content part handler** level.

I wrote a short walkthrough about how to achieve that in an answer for other, very similar SO question - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727843/how-to-change-orchard-record-repository/5086069#5086069).

*After all, if you want to store everything in one place, you can always write your own **IRepository<>** implementation to store content parts, but it's a **lot** of work, and I'd advise you to avoid that unless you really have to.*

HTH

Comment: I will update this item as answered once I have managed to implement your solution proposal.

Comment: Sure, take your time. I hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Hi, did that approach work for you, or maybe you found some other way? I'm curious.