# Should I use Orchard or umbraco or something else?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco, orchardcms

I am building a web site for baby names. Users can submit a name, meaning and some tags, and moderators can edit/approve it. Very small amount of data is used for each entry/post.

Looking for some kind of framework that supports the following features or I can easily extend it,

1. Unicode support
2. I have large number of names, I should be able to import them into my website by code.
3. User roles and permision
4. Some kind of report options. For example, Display list of names that starts with some alphabet or list of names for a #tag
5. Full text search
6. oAuth/OpenID

Are there any frameworks like Orchard, Umbraco I can leverage or would I be better off writing a new ASP.NET MVC application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*If I were you I'd surely stick to some available CMS platforms (Orchard or Umbraco) instead of writing from scratch and reinventing the wheel.*

From my experience with Orchard I can say that setting up a website as you described would be pretty easy and painless with this platform.
Features like those you mention are already available in Orchard, but I guess (as with just about every CMS) this will surely need a little customization to suit your particular need. All the custom functionality could be easily wrapped in a single, [custom content part](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Writing-a-content-part.ashx). How to do that is very well described in the [Orchard documentation](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/).

1. Of course.
2. Without a problem. You have three options: *import directly into Orchard DB* (into the corresponding tables), *import using Orchard Import/Export functionality* (which would involve exporting the data to XML recipe format first) or just *use the current data source without the need of importing*. **There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727843/how-to-change-orchard-record-repository/5086069#5086069) on SO a while ago of getting data from a custom WebService. The solution provided perfectly fits here, so please take a look.**
3. Out of the box - described [here](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Managing-users-and-roles.ashx) and [here](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Understanding-permissions.ashx).
4. I don't know if you meant the backend (admin) view or in the frontend? Tagging and displaying tagged items is available oob. More complex, custom reporting would involve some custom coding (writing a custom content part).
5. Available and described [here](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Search-and-indexing.ashx).
6. Sure! It's available via very nice [OAuth Module](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NGM.OpenAuthentication), written by Nick Mayne. It allows you to bind Orchard accounts with OAuth providers.

I don't have much experience with Umbraco though, so I can't give you any direct help, but I guess it'd be nearly as easy to built your website using it.

Personally, I prefer Orchard for its flexibility, extensibility and code freshness. But the choice is a matter of your personal feeling and preferences. From what I've seen they have very similar functionality, although differ much under-the-hood.