# Orchard CMS right for this? And how to proceed?

Tags: rest, orchardcms

Elo!

The goal is to build a Webshop where all the product categories and products (aswell as user authentication, order placement, order history, etc etc) comes from a REST webservice..

So basically very little data will be stored in the CMS DB..

I've managed to extend the login-part (looking at "Windows Authentication Module"), but im not sure how to proceed with the other parts?

Is the answer here a way to go? However the answer seems to claim that we would need records for each product?
[How to change Orchard record repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727843/how-to-change-orchard-record-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is something you might want to consider. Do you really want to flood the rest service with requests. From the way you put this question (very little data will be stored) it seems like every time someone browses a page, you create a REST request. This usually is not a good idea, so be sure to include some caching.

Then, I doubt it's windows authentication you want for a webshop. Make sure to check out forms authentication.

Then, I guess orchard is something you could consider for this project. Regular webshops usually have so much overhead that it is better to create a webshop (with this specific requiremetn) in a regular CMS, and orchard is very extendable.

One mayor thing is, payment. Make sure you have a good payment processor that works (or that you can make it work) for orchard.

Comment: Caching: Yes
Windows Authentication: No its not what i want, but the "Windows Authentication Module" shows how to extend the Authentication-process for orchard, and i took it from there.

Thanks