# Is it possible to filter dynamic content using orchard default search?

Tags: search, dynamic, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am developing website on Orchard CMS. In this website I have a bunch of pure HTML content pages, for this search working across all these pages and I have a few other additional pages that have dynamic content from database (custom module), for this search is not working.
Is it possible to filter dynamic content using orchard default search?
Is it possible to bind database data without writing any code?
Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18190210/3936440. Basically you need to index your custom data.